# Using math.factorial in a lambda function with reduce()

Tags: python, lambda, permutation, reduce, factorial

I'm attempting to write a function that calculates the number of unique permutations of a string. For example `aaa` would return `1` and `abc` would return `6`.
I'm writing the method like this:

(Pseudocode:)

```
len(string)! / (A!*B!*C!*...)
```

where A,B,C are the number of occurrences of each unique character. For example, the string `'aaa'` would be `3! / 3! = 1`, while `'abc'` would be `3! / (1! * 1! * 1!) = 6`.

My code so far is like this:

```
def permutations(n):
    '''
    returns the number of UNIQUE permutations of n
    '''
    from math import factorial

    lst = []
    n = str(n)
    for l in set(n):
        lst.append(n.count(l))

    return factorial(len(n)) / reduce(lambda x,y: factorial(x) * factorial(y), lst)
```

Everything works fine, except when I try to pass a string that has only one unique character, i.e. `aaa` - I get the wrong answer:

```
>>> perm('abc')
6
>>> perm('aaa')
2
>>> perm('aaaa')
6
```

Now, I can tell the problem is in running the lambda function with factorials on a list of length 1. I don't know why, though. Most other lambda functions works on a list of length 1 even if its expecting two elements:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x * y, [3])
3
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, [3])
3
```

This one doesn't:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: ord(x) + ord(y), ['a'])
'a' 
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: ord(x) + ord(y), ['a','b'])
195
```

Is there something I should be doing differently? I know I can rewrite the function in many different ways that will circumvent this, (e.g. not using `lambda`), but I'm looking for why this specifically doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `reduce` function doesn't always know what the default (initial) value should be. There should be a version that takes an initial value. Supply a sensible initial value and your `reduce` should work beautifully.

Also, from the comments, you should probably just use `factorial` on the second argument in your lambda:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x * factorial(y), lst, 1)
```

Comment: @agf & Platinum Azure - Thanks, this works for a list of size 1, but anything larger fails. Why? The documentation seems to say that the initial value should be treated as if the list was simply one element longer.

Comment: You might try `reduce(lambda x,y: x * factorial(y), lst, 1)`.  The lambda you have calculates like `((1! * 2!)! * 3!)! ...`.

Comment: Are you sure that you should be using `factorial(x)` on the first argument? If you want the product of all the factorials, you should use `reduce(lambda x,y: x * factorial(y), lst, 1)`.

Comment: @cHao & Platinum Azure. Thanks! That did fix it.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce), there is an optional 'initializer' argument that is placed before all other elements in the list so that the behavior for one element lists is consistent, for example, for your `ord()` lambda you could set `initializer` to the the character with an `ord()` of 0:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: ord(x) + ord(y), ['a'], chr(0))
97
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `len(s)! / A!*B!*C!` then the use of `reduce()` won't work, as it will calculate `factorial(factorial(A)*factorial(B))*factorial(C)`. In other words, it really needs the operation to be commutative.

Instead, you'll need to generate the list of factorials, then multiply them together:

```
import operator
reduce(operator.mul, [factorial(x) for x in lst])
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce works by first computing the result for the **first two elements in the sequence** and then pseudo-recursively follows from there. A list of size 1 is a special case.

I would use a list comprehension here:

```
prod( [ factorial(val) for val in lst ] )
```

Good luck!